# Some SharePoint 2007 Designer Workflow actions don't pop up when selected under SSL

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow-activity, designer-workflow

I can't seem to get SharePoint Designer 2007 to give me a dialog box when I select Workflow actions **SEND EMAIL EXTENDED** OR 3rd party **LOOKUP SITE USER PROPERTY**. I select the action, and nothing happens - No errors no event entries .. nothing.  **The problem only happens on one web application that happens to be under SSL**.

I've removed and reinstall a fresh copy of SPD 2007. I've cleared my cache. I've tried on another client.  Other users have reported the same problem.

I figure it's either SSL related or some feature conflict.

Answer (score 1):

At my old company, we had 2007 running under SSL and had the Useful Sharepoint Designer Activites installed without any problems. The issue probably lies elsewhere. You might want to bring this up with the codeplex author.